# Invalid Django formset

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I have a django formset, when I enter just one row of data it works. If I try to enter two or more rows of data, when I submit the form I get the error:

```
ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with. Missing fields: form-TOTAL_FORMS, form-INITIAL_FORMS.
```

Reading similar questions it seems missing the management_form but in my code is present..any ideas?
This is my code:

models.py and forms.py

```
#models.py

from django.db import models

class Station(models.Model):
    id_station = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    station_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    unity_name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=10)
    id_sensor = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    sensor_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'station'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import Station
from django.forms import formset_factory

class StationForm(forms.Form):
    id_station = forms.IntegerField(label='id della stazione') #, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Book Name here'}))
    station_name = forms.CharField(label='nome stazione', max_length=30,
                                   widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'nome stazione'}))
    unity_name = forms.CharField(label='nome unita', max_length=10,
                                   widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'nome unita'}))
    id_sensor = forms.IntegerField(label='id sensore')
    sensor_name = forms.CharField(label='nome sensore', max_length=50,
                                  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'nome sensore'}))

StationFormset = formset_factory(StationForm, extra=1)
```

views.py

```
from django.template import RequestContext

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import StationFormset
from .models import Station

def new_station(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    template_name = 'station.html'
    heading_message = 'Add a new station'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = StationFormset(request.GET or None)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset = StationFormset(request.POST or None)
        print('formset: ', formset.non_form_errors())

        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                id_station = form.cleaned_data.get("id_station")
                station_name = form.cleaned_data.get("station_name")
                unity_name = form.cleaned_data.get("unity_name")
                id_sensor = form.cleaned_data.get("id_sensor")
                print('id sensor: ', id_sensor)
                sensor_name = form.cleaned_data.get("sensor_name")
            # save instance
                #form.save()
            return redirect('new_station')
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'formset': formset,
        'heading': heading_message,
    })
```

station.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Inserisci una nuova stazione</h1>

<form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="row form-row">

        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}


          <div class="col-6">
               <label>{{ form.id_station.label }}</label>
            {{form.id_station}}
          </div>
          <div class="col">
               <label>{{ form.station_name.label }}</label>
               {{form.station_name}}
          </div>
          <div class="col">
               <label>{{ form.unity_name.label }}</label>
            {{form.unity_name}}
          </div>
          <div class="col">
               <label>{{ form.id_sensor.label }}</label>
            {{form.id_sensor}}
          </div>
          <div class="col">
               <label>{{ form.sensor_name.label }}</label>
            {{form.sensor_name}}
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+ Unità e sensori</button>
          </div>

  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  <div class="row spacer">
    <div class="col-4 offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Invia</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
    var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
    var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
    if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
    if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
    if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
}
function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name')
        if(name) {
            name = name.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
            var id = 'id_' + name;
            $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var forValue = $(this).attr('for');
        if (forValue) {
          forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
          $(this).attr({'for': forValue});
        }
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);
    var conditionRow = $('.form-row:not(:last)');
    conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-row')
    .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
    .removeClass('add-form-row').addClass('remove-form-row')
    .html('-');
    return false;
}
function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
    var total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
    if (total > 1){
        btn.closest('.form-row').remove();
        var forms = $('.form-row');
        $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
        for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
            $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function() {
                updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
            });
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'form');
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteForm('form', $(this));
    return false;
});

</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Reading similar questions it seems missing in the html template the management_form but in my code is present..any ideas?

Comment: define your formset on top before any condition in view.py.

Comment: Great! It seems work! Thak you!